# symfony 3 формы EntityType значение null передается всегда

Tags: symfony, forms

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($project)
        ->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Название проекта'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('companyId', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Company',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ])
```

вот кусок формы. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'company_id' cannot be null при отправке формы. Обьясните пожалуйста новичку где туплю.
Ниже дебаг отправки формы

```
    object(stdClass)#421 (10) {
     ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(24) "AppBundle\Entity\Project"
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
  ["companyId"]=>
  object(stdClass)#569 (7) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(24) "AppBundle\Entity\Company"
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["name"]=>
    string(18) "Компания 2"
    ["createdAt"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["updatedAt"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["projects"]=>
    string(8) "Array(1)"
    ["transactions"]=>
    string(8) "Array(0)"
  }
  ["price"]=>
  float(23)
  ["cost"]=>
  float(23)
  ["createdAt"]=>
  NULL
  ["updatedAt"]=>
  NULL
  ["company"]=>
  NULL
  ["transactions"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

А это таблица в которую пытаюсь записать

```
    CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(14,2) NOT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(14,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Непонятен вопрос, вы пишите что передаёте null в `companyId`, и видите ошибку что `company_id` не может быть null. Возможно здесь и ответ? Не надо передавать null..

Comment: Попробую сформулировать иначе. Есть форма. в ней вызывается сущность Company (тег select). Во вьюшке это селект с компаниями (id,name) он работает. Когда я сохраняю форму то в Insert значение company_id(id из сущности) передается null. Я пошел дальше и сделал принт того что там из сущности передается и увидел что там обьект с кучей полей. И поэтому null. Как мне вернуть не обьект а только id для сохранения данных после отправки формы.

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть ваши сущности (Entity), вообще в companyId судя по вашей форме должна лежать сущность Company, а не её id, т.к. у вас EntityType. Я не понимаю зачем вы пытаетесь сохранить именно id. У вас в сущностях должна быть связь ... попробуйте почитать тут http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Comment: я добавил дебаг формы после сабмита. companyId object а мне его нужно засунуть в таблицу как поле company_id

Comment: Покажите сущность, т.е. вам связь не нужна? Если связи нет - то просто замените ее на $company->getId() .. а вообще доктрина сама записывает id если есть связи ...

Comment: Сущность какую показать? Project или Company?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58960/discussion-between-danil-and-durrasell).

Comment: Спасибо помогли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо danil. Ответ был прост. Было взято свойство companyId а связка была на свойство company